# Monitor goes to sleep

Tags: sleep, power

I set all my power settings to "always on", but the power to my monitor is turned off routinely after ten minutes.  I've tried everything from settings in the control panel to settings in monitors - nothing affects this, including the "automatic sleep inhibitor" I keep on the taskbar.  Any suggestions?  I would like to be able to watch a long video without having to move the mouse every ten minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you are on Windows - check if it was the right  profile, i.e. the energy profile/plan that is really active, that you edited. You can end up editing plugged settings when you want 'on battery', or an energy save plan when performance is active, etc., or your editing may result in a new, user defined plan, that still needs to be chosen instead of the presets.